# Electron app with iframe gets scrollbars in fullscreen mode

Tags: iframe, electron, fullscreen, chromium

I am trying to make this Electron app have an iframe that takes up the entire content area.  For the test, I'm setting my resolution to 1920x1080.  The content being loaded has a blue div at that same resolution.  The app renders tall by a few pixels, which forces two scrollbars.  I cannot figure out how to get it to render without the scrollbars at that resolution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Test repo:
https://github.com/thomasdunn/electron-fullscreen-iframe-test

Comment: Is there some kind of hidden margin/padding going on? I see you put `margin: 0` on your `body` but you could try the `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }` trick in your CSS to take it one step further to see if that's the root cause.

Comment: Thank you @Erick - I tried that and it didn't work.  But you got me thinking again and I tried `overflow: hidden` on body and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was simply to put `overflow: hidden` on body.  It then shows the complete document without scrollbars.  Still not sure why this is necessary, but it works.